# how to register a class method as a control event handler

Tags: asp.net, gridview, delegates

Pardon my ignorance of delegates. I'm trying to register a handler for a GridView event in an asp.net WinForms page:

```
Class myClass
{
    void grid_rowDataBound(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    { blah blah }
}

myClass myClassInstance = new myClass(); //done in Page_Load

<asp:GridView ID="server_grid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="myClassInstance.grid_RowDataBound">
    yadda yadda
</asp:GridView>
```

I am getting a runtime error "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'". My only solution at this point is to define a new page function that simply calls my class method and register that page function in OnRowDataBound. But isn't there a direct way to register a class method for GridView events without the indirection? Or do all page contol events require handlers defined in the page class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following, but then this is just a short way of defining a new function like you already suggested.

```
server_grid.RowDataBound += (s,e) => myClassInstance.grid_RowDataBound(s, e);
```

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. I'd still like to understand why I'm getting the error but this is a short 'n sweet workaround.

Comment: Most probably the class is not instantiated yet when the delegate is assigned. The controls are already there before you reach the `Page_Load` where you instantiate the class.